# iOS: How to know reloadData() was completed its task?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I want to scroll to a given index (`self.boldRowPath`), but when I debug `scrollToRow` is performed before `reloadData()`.

How to know `reloadData` has finished ?

```
func getAllTimeEvent()  {
    self.arrAllTimeEvent = ModelManager.getInstance().getAllTimeEvent(from: self.apportmentDateFrom, to: self.apportmentDateTo)
    self.tblTimeEvent.reloadData()
    self.tblTimeEvent.scrollToRow(at: self.boldRowPath ?? [0,0], at: .top, animated: true)
 }
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you see [How to tell when UITableVIew has completed ReloadData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071503/how-to-tell-when-uitableview-has-completed-reloaddata). It's in objective-c but the answers provided there are more complete...

Comment: @Honey this is ask before 8 month ago and i did't find this link bcoz there is no tag for swift  so i did't reach this link throw google .

Comment: Understood, exactly because this question is marked as Swift...is the reason I didn't mark it as duplicate :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try doing this, it should work:

```
self.tblTimeEvent.reloadData()
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    self.tblTimeEvent.scrollToRow(at: self.boldRowPath ?? [0,0], at: .top, animated: true)
})
```

This will execute the scrollToRow on the main thread, that means after the reloadData is done (because it is on the main thread)

Comment: ummm. shouldn't the tableview reload itself on main thread ALL the time? Isn't it a UI update?!

Comment: When you call reloadData(), it reloads itself on the main thread so you cannot scroll the tableview while it is reloading. You call it on the main thread so it is queued to begin right after the reloadData is done. @Honey

Answer (score 5):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16071589/2846494), the reload of the `UITableView` happens on the next layout run (usually, when you return control to the run loop).

So, you can schedule your code after the next layout by using the main dispatch queue. In your case:

```
    func getAllTimeEvent()  {
        self.arrAllTimeEvent = ModelManager.getInstance().getAllTimeEvent(from: self.apportmentDateFrom, to: self.apportmentDateTo)
        self.tblTimeEvent.reloadData()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tblTimeEvent.scrollToRow(at: self.boldRowPath ?? [0,0], at: .top, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

You can also force the layout by manually calling `layoutIfNeeded`. But this is generally not a good idea (the previous option is the best):

```
    func getAllTimeEvent()  {
        self.arrAllTimeEvent = ModelManager.getInstance().getAllTimeEvent(from: self.apportmentDateFrom, to: self.apportmentDateTo)
        self.tblTimeEvent.reloadData()
        self.tblTimeEvent.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.tblTimeEvent.scrollToRow(at: self.boldRowPath ?? [0,0], at: .top, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**you can make sure reload is done using...**

**In Swift 3.0 +** we can create a an extension for `UITableView` with a `escaped  Closure` like below :

```
extension UITableView {
    func reloadData(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, animations: { self.reloadData()})
        {_ in completion() }
    }
}
```

**And Use it like Below where ever you want :**

```
Your_Table_View.reloadData {
   print("reload done")
 }
```

**hope this will help to someone. cheers!**

Comment: Thanks Anuradth i will check this one

Answer (score 1):

You can make a pretty solid assumption that a `UITableView` is done reloading when the last time `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)` is called for the visible sections on the screen.

So try something like this (for a tableView where the rows in section 0 take up the available space on the screen):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let lastRowIndex = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
  if indexPath.row == lastRowIndex - 1 {
    // tableView done reloading
    self.tblTimeEvent.scrollToRow(at: self.boldRowPath ?? [0,0], at: .top, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Comment: tableview:willdisplay:forrowat: does not get called for all items in the tableview.. but only on the visible rows.. so if tableview is scrolled up, this will not work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CATransaction** for that

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    // Completion
}
tableView.reloadData()
CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score -3):

```
tableView.reloadData { [weak self] in
    self?.doSomething()
}
```

Comment: Such a function does not exist.

Comment: @oddK please check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata