# UICollectionView set default position

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a CollectionView with 3 Cells which extend across the whole device's screen and basically represent my 3 main views.
I have paging enabled, so it basically works exactly like the iOS home screen right now.
My problem is that I want the "default" position of this CollectionView to be equal to `view.frame.width` so that the second Cell is the "default" view and I can swipe left and right to get to my secondary views.

I have already tried via

```
collectionView.scrollToItem()
```

and

```
collectionView.scrollRectToVisible()
```

as well as

```
collectionView.setContentOffset()
```

but they all seem to work only after the view has loaded (I tried them via a button in my navigation bar).
Thank you in advance!
**EDIT:** 
Now this works, but I also have another collection view in that one middle cell which holds a list of little 2-paged `UICollectionView`s which are actually objects from a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` called `PersonCell` each holding a `UICollectionView`. I want these UICollectionViews to be scrolled to index 1 as well, this is my code:

```
for tabcell in (collectionView?.visibleCells)! {
    if let maincell: MainCell = tabcell as? MainCell {
        for cell in maincell.collectionView.visibleCells {
            if let c = cell as? PersonCell {
                c.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: (NSIndexPath(item: 1, section: 0) as IndexPath), at: [], animated: false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is executed in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of my 'root' `CollectionViewController`.

**EDIT 2:**
Now I tried using following code in the `MainCell` class (it's a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let personCell = cell as! PersonCell
    personCell.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: (NSIndexPath(item: 1, section: 0) as IndexPath), at: [], animated: false)
}
```

**EDIT 3:**

Long story short, I basically need a delegate method that is called *after* a cell has been added to the `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it!
This SO answer gave me the final hint:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16071589/3338129

Basically, now I just do this after initialization of the Cell:

```
self.collectionView.alpha = 1
self.data = data // array is filled with data
self.collectionView.reloadData()
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    for cell in self.collectionView.visibleCells {
        (cell as! PersonCell).collectionView.scrollToItem(at: (NSIndexPath(item: 1, section: 0) as IndexPath), at: [], animated: false)
    }
    self.collectionView.alpha = 1
}
```

Basically, the code in the DispatchQueue.main.async{...} is called on the next UI refresh cycle which means at a point where the cells are already there. To prevent the user from seeing the wrong page for a fraction of a second, I set the whole collectionView's alpha to 0 and toggle it on as soon as the data is there, the cell is there and the page has scrolled.

Comment: In my case, I push the view controller in a navBarVC, the page will blink when the collectionView alpha changed from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath                              atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];`

Try calling the code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: But I'm not totally there, yet ;)