# Method tableView.reloadData() asynchronous execution

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

My code:

```
...
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.someOldValue = self.someNewValue
...
```

TableView delegate and datasource methods work with self.someOldValue. I need use self.someOldValue in those methods before it changes. How to do it? Method reloadData() works asynchronous and tableView delegate and datasource methods works with newValue already(`self.someOldValue = self.someNewValue` executes before `self.tableView.reloadData()`)

Comment: Why don't you make the data source methods work with the old value instead?

Comment: put the second line inside the aync method's done callback. so you will be sure that line will be executed after `tableView.reloadData()` completed.

Comment: Take a look at the answers to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071503/how-to-tell-when-uitableview-has-completed-reloaddata