# How to access a NSOutlineView after reloadData completes

Tags: macos, reloaddata, nsoutlineview

Although this question has been answered here:

[How to tell when UITableVIew has completed ReloadData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071503/how-to-tell-when-uitableview-has-completed-reloaddata)

The 13 answers are so convoluted with issues and alternatives that I am hopelessly confused.

Would someone, who understands this, synthesize a single answer?

EDIT:  For others who may be following [How to tell when UITableVIew has completed ReloadData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071503/how-to-tell-when-uitableview-has-completed-reloaddata), Nextman's comment below offered a possible solution.

Comment: reloadData is synchronous; it is finished by the time you reach the next line code. The actual view/layout may not get updated until the next pass through the run loop. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My experience as well as the referenced question above seem to indicate that reloadData is not actually completed until the end of the run loop.  Any method that attempts to query the tableView after reloadData but before the the next run loop cycle is initiated fails.  I have inserted data into the data source, then called reloadData. Now, I want to select the new row (item) which requires:  rowForItem, and selectRowIndexes, but rowForItem returns -1.  Perhaps I don't understand.  It wouldn't be the first time.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: `UITableView` ≠ `NSOutlineView` but `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});` should work. How do you add a row? Please add your code to the question.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to show a reproducible example of your issue. I just tried a simple test of an array-backed `NSOutlineView` and I am able to insert a row, call `reloadData`, and then select the row with `rowForItem` and `selectRowIndexes`. It works fine all in the same method call, without need to dispatch.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Myc2VwfT

Comment: MY SINCERE APPOLOGIES.  I sent setNeedsDisplay to the wrong outlet.