# Content Inset change when UITableView Reload Sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an expandable `UITableView`. When user tap on a header, the related cell will be shown with an animation (RowAnimation.Fade) and then `UITableView` scrolls to that header (expanded header). When the user taps again to that header, It collapses.

What I want to **achieve**: I need to have an expandable UITableView with header and cells. When user tap header, cells need to be opened with `RowAnimation.Fade` and then scroll to that header.

Bonus: Also If I can get the arrow animate when user taps on the header will be great but I think this cause another bug, cuz we run so much animation on the same thread (Main thread)

**My problem** is that when a user taps to the header, tableView content inset changes and whole headers goes on minus Y position. So a weird animation occurs. (For example, headers, looks center of a cell)  However, after the animation finish, everything looks correct.

```
func toggleSection(header: DistrictTableViewHeader, section: Int) {
self.selectedHeaderIndex = section
self.cities[section].isCollapsed = !self.cities[section].isCollapsed
let contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset
self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: section), with: UITableView.RowAnimation.fade)
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: NSNotFound, section: section) /* you can pass NSNotFound to scroll to the top of the section even if that section has 0 rows */, at: UITableView.ScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
}
```

In addition: I set the height of headers and cells like in below.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 140
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header: DistrictTableViewHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: headerId) as! DistrictTableViewHeader
    //let header = DistrictTableViewHeader()

    header.customInit(title: self.cities[section].name, section: section, delegate: self,isColapsed: self.cities[section].isCollapsed,isSelectedHeader: section == selectedHeaderIndex ? true : false)
    return header
}
```

My custom headerView Class:

```
protocol ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate {
func toggleSection(header: DistrictTableViewHeader, section: Int)
}

class DistrictTableViewHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
var delegate: ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate?
var section: Int!

let nameLabel: UILabel = {
   let l = UILabel()
    l.textColor = Color.DistrictsPage.headerTextColor
    return l
}()

private let arrowImage: UIImageView = {
  let i = UIImageView()
    let image = UIImage(named: "ileri")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
    i.image = image
    i.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return i
}()
var willAnimate: Bool = false
var isColapsed: Bool!{
    didSet{
        expandCollapseHeader()
    }
}

private func expandCollapseHeader(){
    if(willAnimate){
        if(!self.isColapsed){
            let degrees : Double = 90 //the value in degrees
            self.nameLabel.textColor = Color.Common.garantiLightGreen
            self.arrowImage.tintColor = Color.Common.garantiLightGreen
            self.arrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: CGFloat(degrees * .pi/180))
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.97, green:0.97, blue:0.97, alpha:1.0)
        }else{
            let degrees : Double = 0 //the value in degrees
            self.nameLabel.textColor = Color.DistrictsPage.headerTextColor
            self.arrowImage.tintColor = UIColor.black
            self.arrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: CGFloat(degrees * .pi/180))
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
    }else{
        if(!isColapsed){
            let degrees : Double = 90 //the value in degrees
            self.nameLabel.textColor = Color.Common.garantiLightGreen
            self.arrowImage.tintColor = Color.Common.garantiLightGreen
            self.arrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: CGFloat(degrees * .pi/180))
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.97, green:0.97, blue:0.97, alpha:1.0)
        }else{
            let degrees : Double = 0 //the value in degrees
            self.nameLabel.textColor = Color.DistrictsPage.headerTextColor
            self.arrowImage.tintColor = UIColor.black
            self.arrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: CGFloat(degrees * .pi/180))
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
        layoutSubviews()
    }
}

override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {

    super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectHeaderAction)))
    nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    nameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
    nameLabel.textColor = Color.DistrictsPage.headerTextColor
    contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
    nameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    nameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true

    arrowImage.tintColor =  UIColor(red:0.32, green:0.36, blue:0.36, alpha:1.0)
    arrowImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(arrowImage)
    arrowImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    arrowImage.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    arrowImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
func rotate(_ toValue: CGFloat) {
    self.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: toValue)
}
@objc func selectHeaderAction(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let cell = gestureRecognizer.view as! DistrictTableViewHeader
    delegate?.toggleSection(header: self, section: cell.section)
}


func customInit(title: String, section: Int, delegate: ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate,isColapsed: Bool, isSelectedHeader: Bool) {
    self.nameLabel.text = title
    self.nameLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = title
    self.section = section
    self.delegate = delegate
    self.willAnimate = isSelectedHeader
    self.isColapsed = isColapsed
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

}
}
```

In the below picture, bug is seen clearly. When "Some Data" and "Another City" is open and u tap on "Some Data". Animation bug occurs. "Another city" goes above Its' cell and then goes up. What should be done is "Another city" should stay in Its' place and then move up when "Some Data" cell is closing.
[image]
**Example Project:** https://github.com/emreond/tableViewLayoutIssue

Comment: Why this question gets down vote? can you please explain?

Comment: Hello @Emre, I just read your question, but i am unable to identify what issue in animation, Can you just make small video or gif and put the link over here... so that i can get exact issue. One more thing... if you have any other sample(may be app or design) which describes what is your expected behaviour then that will be better to understand your issue. btw, I am not a person to downvote your question.

Comment: Hello, I edited my question and tried to explain it more clearly on screenshot explanation. Another city header goes above It's cell and then moves up. However, It should stay same because I only close Some Data not Another City.

Comment: let say A, B and C are 3 section, now if you close the section B, then it is obvious that contentOffset of tableview will remain same. So, section C will come in upward direction. Also, if (contentOffset.y + screensize.height)  will be greater than contentSize, then in that case, contentOffset's y position will also get updated(will go down in this case).

Comment: I think this is normal behaviour, if my understanding with your question is proper one.

Comment: Problem is section B y position goes 100 to 120 then goes to 80. I think proper animation should be 100 to 80.

Comment: this must be happening if you are at last cell. If you are having limited cities, then add fake cities and make it enough scrollable then check that is it happening for if last cell is visible OR in all cases. As per my knowledge, this should only happen in case of last cell

Comment: But I’m opening NOT the last cell

Comment: @EmreÖnder Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071503/how-to-tell-when-uitableview-has-completed-reloaddata

Comment: I’ll check it but as I searched, reloaddata has no animation so that there will be no problem

Comment: still searching for solution? or found one

Comment: Still searching

Comment: do you want to do something like this? confirm if yes. enable flash on browser if does not play. https://screencast.com/t/KJkb3zoEb9z7

Comment: i used completely different approach then you and less code as well and working superb for me.

Comment: What did you use?

Comment: i used RATreeView. its a wrapper created using tableview at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I need to solve it in this way :( and find what causes this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After days of search and tries, I found that changing `UITableViewStyle` to the group do the trick. Therefore, I changed initializing `UITableView` to

`let tableView = UITableView.init(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .grouped)`

In addition for scrolling, I needed to add `CATransaction` to catch the completion.

```
CATransaction.begin()
DispatchQueue.main.async {
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    // Code to be executed upon completion
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: NSNotFound, section: section) /* you can pass NSNotFound to scroll to the top of the section even if that section has 0 rows */, at: UITableView.ScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
}
    self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet.init(integer: section), with: UITableView.RowAnimation.fade)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, you can use this as a fix :

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: section), with: .fade)
}
```

Of course, you lose the animation but also the flicker.

Comment: But I also want the animation as I asked in my question.