# Scrolling to bottom of a section in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am trying to write a function that scrolls to the bottom cell of a given section in my tableView, I'm calling this function after my `tableView.reloadData()` function but it is not scrolling, any ideas why?

```
func scrollToBottom(section: Int){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.session[section].count - 1, section: section)
            self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess you are scrolling to early. Try calling tableView layoutIfNeeded before scrolling

Comment: you can also try this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39798079/2303865

Answer (score 0):

You don't need put code in `DispatchQueue.main` because it already run on main thread.

Try this

```
func scrollToBottom(section: Int){
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.session[section].count - 1, section: section)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }
```